# Please explain the order in which recursive prolog programs run

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and was wondering if someone could explain the below procedure, since I'm struggling to understand the step-by-step process prolog follows when this procedure is executed. I would like to know how to read the order in which things are run in a recursive prolog procedures.

If we look at the examples below we can see that the palindrome procedure is called again in the body with variable H1 and I've heard that this is done by the procedure until it hits the base case which works it's way up from the base case to produce the result, but I'm really struggling to lay out the steps on how it gets to the result from the first call.

```
palindrome([]).
palindrome([_]).
palindrome([First|Rest]):-
    append(H1,[First],Rest),
    palindrome(H1).
```

Why does the second argument ( [First] ) in append have the [ ] and when running the palindrome procedure does it first complete the palindrome functor on the inside before retrying the main palindrome functor? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can use `trace` and `gtrace` etc. to see what's going on: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 1):

```
?- trace(append/3).
%     swipl/boot/messages.pl:1103: [all]
true.

?- trace(palindrome/1).
%     swipl/boot/messages.pl:1103: [all]

?- palindrome([a,b,b]).
 T [10] Call: palindrome([a, b, b])
 T [17] Call: lists:append(_14142, [a], [b, b])
 T [24] Call: lists:append(_15126, [a], [b])
 T [31] Call: lists:append(_522, [a], [])
 T [31 +0.3ms] Fail: lists:append(_522, [a], [])
 T [24 +0.5ms] Fail: lists:append(_358, [a], [b])
 T [17 +0.8ms] Fail: lists:append(_192, [a], [b, b])
 T [10 +1.2ms] Fail: palindrome([a, b, b])
false.

?- palindrome([a,b,a]).
 T [10] Call: palindrome([a, b, a])
 T [17] Call: lists:append(_6912, [a], [b, a])
 T [24] Call: lists:append(_7896, [a], [a])
 T [24 +0.4ms] Exit: lists:append([], [a], [a])
 T [17 +0.7ms] Exit: lists:append([b], [a], [b, a])
 T [17] Call: palindrome([b])
 T [17 +0.2ms] Exit: palindrome([b])
 T [10 +1.4ms] Exit: palindrome([a, b, a])
true .
```

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to understand exactly what the `append` is doing, which is: adding H1 and First immediately to the *right of* First.

H1 can be an empty list, or a single-element list.

`[First]` is a single-element list, because append/3 operates on lists.

A `writeln` helps to show the flow:

```
palindrome([]).
palindrome([_]).
palindrome([First|Rest]):-
    append(H1,[First],Rest),
    writeln(Rest),
    palindrome(H1).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- palindrome(L).
L = [] ;
L = [_] ;
...
[_68,_80,_92,_106,_1400,_2716,_4068,_5448,_6870,_8326,_9830,_11374,_54]
[_80,_92,_106,_1400,_2716,_4068,_5448,_6870,_8326,_9830,_68]
[_92,_106,_1400,_2716,_4068,_5448,_6870,_8326,_80]
[_106,_1400,_2716,_4068,_5448,_6870,_92]
[_1400,_2716,_4068,_5448,_106]
[_2716,_4068,_1400]
[_2716]
L = [_A, _B, _C, _D, _E, _F, _G, _G, _F, _E, _D, _C, _B, _A] ;
```

This makes it more obvious that the list is being cut into 2-element slices, i.e. H1 and First, due to the `append`.

This `append` method is unintuitive, and increasingly slow, as seen by:

```
?- time(palindrome(L)).
...
% 160 inferences
% 171 inferences
% 186 inferences
```

Alternatively: the [DCG method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342087/) is both intuitive and fast. Is also mentioned at https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg